# Classifying extensions of a $k$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

*Background*.
Let $k\to A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra, $I$ an $A$-module. According to Sernesi's notation, I'll denote by $\textrm{Ex}_k(A,I)$ the $A$-module of isomorphism classes of $k$-extensions
$$\eta: \,\,\,\,\,0\to I\to A'\to A\to 0$$
of $A$ by $I$ (the surjection is a $k$-algebra homomorphism, by definition).

Let us write $A$ as a quotient of a polynomial algebra $P=k[x]$:
$$0\to J\to P\to A\to 0.$$
The conormal sequence $J/J^2\to \Omega_{P/k}\otimes_PA\to \Omega_{A/k}\to 0$
induces a map 
$$\alpha:\textrm{Hom}_A(\Omega_{P/k}\otimes_PA,I) \to \textrm{Hom}_A(J/J^2,I).$$

---

I am trying to prove the following:

$$\color{blue}{\textrm{Ex}_k(A,I)\cong\textrm{coker } \alpha}.$$

---

We have thus fixed an extension $\eta$ as above. Now, as $P$ is a smooth $k$-algebra, the map $P\to A$ lifts to a map $g:P\to A'$ (this is the *infinitesimal lifting property*). I think the main point here is: in how many ways?

If $I$ has generators $\{e_i\}$ over $A$, and $y=\{y_i\}$ is a set of variables indexed like the $e_i$'s, $g$ induces exactly one morphism $$Q:=P\otimes k[y]\to A'$$ compatible with $g$.

I want to show that moving in the isomorphism class of $\eta$ is the same as moving in the set of possible liftings $P\to A'$ or, which is the same, in the set of possible morphisms $Q\to A'$.

There is only one thing I know, and I am unable to use it. What I know is that if I have two liftings $g,g'$, their difference $g-g':P\to I$ is an element of $\textrm{Der}_k(P,I)$. Conversely, the sum of a lifting and a such derivation is a new lifting. Moreover, I was able to show that
$$\textrm{Hom}_A(\Omega_{P/k}\otimes_PA,I)\cong\textrm{Hom}_P(\Omega_{P/k},I)\cong\textrm{Der}_k(P,I).$$
So I can view $\alpha$ as a morphism $\textrm{Der}_k(P,I)\to \textrm{Hom}_A(J/J^2,I)$.
But I cannot go further, e.g. I am not sure that $\eta$ defines a uniquely determined map $J/J^2\to I$ in the target of $\alpha$.

How can I conclude from here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Except for the e.f.t. hypothesis, this looks similar to Sernesi's Proposition 1.1.7. Have you looked at whether his proof can be modified? In fact, I don't think he uses e.f.t. until he appeals to the appendix for the last statement.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but the cokernel of $\alpha$ can also be identified with $\operatorname{Ext}^1_A(\Omega_{A/k},I)$. The elements of this ext group are in bijective correspondence with isomorphism classes of $A$-modules $B$ that fit into $0\to \Omega_{A/k} \to B \to I \to 0$. Perhaps there's something to extract out of here.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks for your comment! yes, I tried to do what you say, as Sernesi's is one of the books I am studying. But I cannot come up with a non tautological argument. My goal is to define abstractly an isomorphism, while in Sernesi one uses a certain versal extension to have the last surjective map.